# Is there any difference b/w goto &func; and &func; in Perl?

Tags: perl, goto

```
goto &func;

&func;
```

They two seems identical to me after some test,is that the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a substantial difference.  Check here: [perl-goto](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html)

Comment: so the only difference is that the current function won't show in the call stack of `func`,right?

Comment: They are significantly different in control flow for this reason. The goto doesn't return, so statements after it will not be executed. The call does return, so statements after it will be executed. Typically there aren't any, as `goto &func;` is a manual way of doing tail recursive optimisation.

Answer (score 4):

You were running the wrong tests. Use [caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) to see what is going on.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub foo {
  my $level = 0;
  while (my $sub = (caller($level))[3]) {
    print "$sub\n";
    ++$level;
  }
  print "\n";
}

sub bar {
  print "sub:\n";
  &foo;
}

sub baz {
  print "goto:\n";
  goto &foo;
}

bar();
baz();
```

When you run it, you'll see something like:

```
$  ~/stuff/goto
sub:
main::foo
main::bar

goto:
main::foo
```

Comment: Place a print statement at the bottom of `bar` and `baz` for the full effect.

Comment: So the only difference is that it'll disappear from the call stack if you use goto?

Comment: No. As Eric says, if you add print statements at the end of bar() and baz() you'll see the other effect.